# casperjs fake flash supper

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

as far as I know casperJS & phantomJS don't support flash anymore. Is there any possilibty to fake the Flashsupport in capserJS, so I don't get any warnings that flash isn't running etc...

Would be nice if someone would have a pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve flash support only when started using old version of phantomjs 1.4.0